# Types of neutron stars

Tags: astrophysics, neutron-stars

Do we know what are deciding factors for creating different types of neutron stars? I well familiar with how neutron stars being formed and how different types works. What I don't understand is what are the deciding factors for what star collapse into after supernova:  radio pulsar, rycycled pulsar, magnetar, sgr,axp,lmxb etc.